# OpenCL - Setting up local memory for a large dataset

Tags: opencl

I have the following problem. I have 6000 * 1000 elements that i need to work on in parallel (for most of the part). However, at some part of the kernel, those 6000 items have to summed together.

When I tried to setup my kernel inputs where (globalThreads = 6000 * 1000, localThreads = 6000), it seemed to throw an error (CL_INVALID_WORK_GROUP_SIZE). It seems that the maximum number of local elements in a workgroup is limited.

How can I work around this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can't set local threads that high. Most hardware can only do 128 to 1024 or so local threads (clGetDeviceInfo with CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE will tell you for your device). You can leave the local size NULL and the runtime will pick a size for you, but if your global size is not multiple of your devices work group size, this might not give you optimal performance. For top performace you can experiment with different local sizes, and then specify both, but the global must be a multiple of the local size in OpenCL 1.x. Round up the global and then check the work item index in your kernel to see if it is below your real work size.

Comment: Max compute units:     15
  Max work items dimensions:    3
    Max work items[0]:     1024
    Max work items[1]:     1024
    Max work items[2]:     64
  Max work group size:     1024

I seem to have the following parameters, does this mean i have to divide by data into 1024 size chunks?

Comment: In your question, you are spawning multiple of 1024 threads but using only multiple of 1000 threads. Make local size 1000. İf total work is falling sand, then each grain is local size. 1000. You cant partition a grain for version 1.2.

Comment: Max work group size: 1024 means your local size can't be greater than 1024 on this device. Also, global size must be an integer multiple of local size (in OpenCL 1.x). Like I said, you can leave local size unspecified if you don't want to deal with these rules (but you might not get optimal performance).